# Reading a Python File to EOF while performing if statments

Tags: python, loops, concatenation

I am working on creating a program to concatenate rows within a file. Each file has a header, datarows labeled DAT001 to DAT113 and a trailer. Each line of concatenated rows will have DAT001 to DAT100 and 102-113 is optional. I need to print the header, concatenating DAT001-113 and when the file finds a row with DAT001 I need to start a new line concatenating DAT001-113 again. After that is all done, I will print the trailer. I have an IF statement started but it only writes the header and skips all other logic. I apologize that this is very basic - but I am struggling with reading rows over and over again without knowing how long the file might be.

I have tried the below code but it won't read or print after the header.

```
import pandas as pd
destinationFile = "./destination-file.csv"
sourceFile = "./TEST.txt"
header = "RHR"
data = "DPSPOS"
beg_data = "DAT001"
data2 = "DAT002"
data3 = "DAT003"
data4 = "DAT004"
data5 = "DAT005"
data6 = "DAT006"
data7 = "DAT007"
data8 = "DAT008"
data100 = "DAT100"
data101 = "DAT101"
data102 = "DAT102"
data103 = "DAT103"
data104 = "DAT104"
data105 = "DAT105"
data106 = "DAT106"
data107 = "DAT107"
data108 = "DAT108"
data109 = "DAT109"
data110 = "DAT110"
data111 = "DAT111"
data112 = "DAT112"
data113 = "DAT113"



req_data = ''
opt101 = ''
opt102 = ''

with open(sourceFile) as Tst:
    for line in Tst.read().split("\n"):
        if header in line: 
            with open(destinationFile, "w+") as dst:
                dst.write(line)
        elif data in line:
            if beg_data in line: 
                req_data = line+line+line+line+line+line+line+line+line
                if data101 in line: 
                    opt101 = line
                    if data102 in line: 
                        opt102 = line
            new_line = pd.concat(req_data,opt101,opt102)
            with open(destinationFile, "w+") as dst:
                dst.write(new_line)
        else:
            if trailer in line:
                with open(destinationFile, "w+") as dst:
                    dst.write(line)
```

Comment: You are opening and closing your destination file at each iteration, which is a bit unusual. But at least you should open it with `a`, not `w`, otherwise you will truncate it each time

Comment: What is `req_data = line+line+line+line+line+line+line+line+line` doing? Why are you  duplicating the line 8 times?

Answer (score 0):

Just open the output file once for the whole loop, not every time through the loop.

Check whether the line begins with `DAT101`. If it does, write the trailer to the current line and start a new line by printing the header.

Then for every line that begins with `DAT`, write it to the file in the current line.

```
first_line = True
with open(sourceFile) as Tst, open(destinationFile, "w+") as dst:
    for line in Tst.read().split("\n"):
        # start a new line when reading DAT101
        if line.startswith(beg_data):
            if not first_line: # need to end the current line
                dst.write(trailer + '\n')
                first_line = False
            dst.write(header)
        # copy all the lines that begin with `DAT`
        if line.startswith('DAT'):
            dst.write(line)
    # end the last line
    dst.write(trailer + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

See if the following code helps make progress. It was not tested  because no
Minimum Runnable Example is provided.

```
with open(destinationFile, "a") as dst:
    # The above will keep the file open until after all the indented code runs
    with open(sourceFile) as Tst:
        # The above will keep the file open until after all the indented code runs
        for line in Tst.read().split("\n"):
            if header in line:
                dst.write(line)
            elif data in line:
                if beg_data in line:
                    req_data = line + line + line + line + line + line + line + line + line
                    if data101 in line:
                        opt101 = line
                        if data102 in line:
                            opt102 = line
                new_line = pd.concat(req_data, opt101, opt102)
                dst.write(new_line)
        else:
            if trailer in line:
                dst.write(line)
# With is a  context manager which will automatically close the files.
```